# Query in C#: how to find data by only 1 number, for example?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

For example, I want to find data about user1 only by two numbers from his ".No".
I tried .Contains, but it doesn't work.

My DB looks like this:

```
User user1 = new User();
    user1.Name = "Bob";
    user1.Surname = "Topson";
    user1.No = 160456;
    user1.Birth = new DateTime (1998, 5, 12);

User user2 = new User();
    user2.Name = "Rob";
    user2.Surname = "Simpson";
    user2.No = 143457;
    user2.Birth = new DateTime (1996, 8, 4);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried?

Comment: .Contains generally is for searching substring in a string, but .No is number type. So, you need to first convert it to toString() and then search by contains

Comment: are you target the above query directly to db or on list objects?

Comment: 1st, I want to find user by year of birth and then replace "14" in .No to "00".

Comment: You should provide an [mcve]. It's not clear in which environment you're working. LINQ can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use StartsWith method if two numbers of NO is unique:

```
 string firstTwo = "14";
 var user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.No.ToString().StartsWith(firstTwo));
```

In this case method Contains returns two items when there is two users with NO numbers:
143457,
151457

Comment: How do you know which two numbers the questioner is wanting to search by? Their question is still vague in that area.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your number in to string

```
user.No =user.No.ToString();
string firstTwo = user.NO.Substring(0, 2)

var record = user.getall().Where(x=>x.No.ToString().Contains(firstTwo).FirstorDefault())
```

Note : It is unclear which two numbers you want to pick , You've to make those two numbers as unique like in this example You've to make the first two number unique through your logic at the time of posting data.
and if it is going to start with 0 index always , You can use StartWith Method instead of contains. As You said you want to replace the first two number with 00 than you've to use string as  a datatype coz int is never going to hold 00 in start.

```
record.No = record.No.replace("firsttwo" , "00")
```

Comment: How do you know which two numbers the questioner is wanting to search by? Their question is still vague in that area.

Comment: in this case he just need to change the index num in substring method ? @NathanWerry Thanks for mentioning

Comment: I want to find by 1st 2 numbers and replace them with "00" for example.

Comment: int is never going to hold 00's in start , You've to use string data type